# "Surprising to" vs. "surprising for"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

Should I say "one thing is quite surprising *to* me" or "one thing is quite surprising *for* me" in the sentence below?

> I've read your article. I am not going to say it's completely dud,
>   don't worry. But one thing is quite surprising [to/for] me: you say in your
>   article that...

Answer (score 1):

IMO, either is fine. But "surprising to" is *much* more common.